# does Apple allows to display MAC address of devices in app

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, mac-address

I thought this could be best place to clarify my doubts and my concern - we about to release our app and it displays MAC address of all connected devices to a router and someone told me apple does not allow to display MAC address and hence app will get rejected.

But there are so many ios apps on itunes which does display MAC address and  how did there app got approved if apple does not allow it.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks,

Comment: My bet is, those other apps are linked against iOS SDK 6 or earlier? Kind of like those apps that display the UDID?

Comment: Maybe the question needs clarification. Are you going to show the info from the router? If that's the case, you could be interested in knowing your MAC address in case you wanted to differentiate your own device only.

Comment: @ lnjuanj - Yes i'm showing  MAC address of all devices connected the router and but concern is will APPLE allow to show mac address ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From iOS 7 or later, the MAC address of an iOS device always returns value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice instead.(`[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`).